# Flask Server side sessions

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm building pythton rest api using flask, flask-login and I would like to store all user sessions (eg. from PC, smarthpone etc.) with expiration dates at PostgreSQL Database. What would be the best approach to achieve this? I know that flask-login can handle customer-side sessions, but that approach cannot manage multiple sessions per one user.
Is it possible to achieve by any flask extensions?

Comment: The flask extension [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) offers server side sessions and the sessions can be stored in Postgres by setting `SESSION_TYPE` to `sqlalchemy`.